# Viewing the Visual SourceSafe log inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Is there any way to view the activity log for the integrate SourceSafe inside Visual Studio 2005 Pro? I'd like to be able to quickly see the results of any Get Latest Version, Check In and Checkout actions, and I can't find a way to get that information without having to open the VSS client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output window (View - Output) echoes a lot.  If it isn't verbose enough though I don't know how one would configure that.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I was missing - I never saw the [Source Control] option for the "Show output from:" setting in the Output window. Great, thanks.